# How can I use the current language as a variable in my masterpage?

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, variations

I'm a web designer working with SharePoint 2013. I created a custom template for a company and now I want to go further with variations capabilities. The website should be available in German and in English.

On the footer of the master page, I placed some hard-coded links like this:

```
<a href="/Authenticate.aspx">Login</a>
<a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
<a href="/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
```

And I want them to rebuild dynamically to my variations site like this for the German language:

```
<a href="/de/...">Login</a>
<a href="/de/...">Imprint</a>
<a href="/de/...">Disclaimer</a>
```

or this for English:

```
<a href="/en/...">Login</a>
<a href="/en/...">Imprint</a>
<a href="/en/...">Disclaimer</a>
```

Is there a variable that I could place in front of the links in my master page? Or a method to get the current language?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
<a href="{Locale}/login">...</a>
<a href="$language/imprint...">...</a>
<a href="getLanguage()/disclaimer">...</a>
```

I'm not an ASP.NET coder, so I don't really know how find out the language. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with another method: I used SharePoints own Javascript variable - **_spPageContextInfo** - see: [_spPageContextInfo is your new best friend](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx) !

With **"currentCultureName"** I could use the language name as a variable to compare to the target language and to expand my PageLayout with custom links, compliant to my variations settings.

The Code could look like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $language = _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName;

        // If it's german, I'll get german links
        if ($language == "de-DE") {
            $('.footer').html('<a href="/de/kontakt/">Kontakt</a>');
        } else {
        // And if not, it will target to the english page
            $('.footer').html('<a href="/en/contact">Contact</a>');
        }

    });
```

Comment: `_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName` it's the method I use too. I see an alternative on Wictor Wilén blog and MSDN discussions using `Strings.STS.L_CurrentUICulture_Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SPWeb.Locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.locale.aspx) property of the current context (as in `SPContext.Current.Web.Locale`) to glean this information.

If you look at the Remarks section of the [CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/kx54z3k7) description on MSDN it will explain this.

A simple example would be:

```
<a href="/<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>/Login.aspx">...</a>
```